# Need a jQuery slider for a flash made movie

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Guys can anyone point me out for this type of slider made in jQuery OR in any other js framework?

http://jandjmediasolutions.com/nse/slider.swf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what exactly you are asking for, but if you haven't already checked out jQuery UI, it has some excellent jQuery slider options (see the examples list on the right):

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Also check out the animation demos:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/